# Refreshing routes are 404ing when I deploy to the server

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I am using react-router v4.  You can see my site shell here.
http://responder.azurewebsites.net/

Click on one of the tabs at the bottom, such as the 3rd tab which goes to here:
http://responder.azurewebsites.net/profile

If you try to refresh this page or click it directly it will 404.

However, on localhost this does not happen and things work well.

Cannot think of why this is working locally but refreshing on the server fails.

Direction would be great!

Here is my router

```
 <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Router>
          <div className="App-content">
            <Route path="/bank" component={BankPage} />
            <Route path="/active-chats" component={ActiveChatsPage} />
            <Route path="/profile" component={ProfilePage} />
            <NavBar />
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
```

Comment: It would probably be worth posting your current react router configuration on this question.

Comment: just edited and added that.   Was late and I forgot it!  @GregHNZ

Comment: I think @giang-le is on the right track. When you navigate within react, it's all handled by javascript. When you refresh, the http server is trying to find that resource, and looking for a specific file.  So you need to tell the http server to redirect all requests to your app.  Are you using a node http server such as `http-server`, `light-server` or `serve` ? (and if so, which?)

Comment: i also had problem with this. you can took my site as well when u click other navigation. and u refresh the page it show error. Has anyone know how to solve this? thanks  https://scenic-kenai-fjords-45848.herokuapp.com/

Comment: I am not using any of those http servers you mentioned yet.  @GregHNZ  However I did find this article from a guy on the discord site https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-react-deployment-5a717d4378fd  under section "React-router not working when typing URL manually"    I am hooking up things with express right now https://daveceddia.com/create-react-app-express-backend/

Answer (score 0):

You shoud to add route to this link. Ex: if you use Express and nodejs on sever side add this

```
express().get('*', function(req, res) {...})
```

If you use Php laravel on server side add this line to route file (web.php)

```
Route::get('/{any?}', 'KeywordController@index');
```

Comment: I don't have anything other than Node at the moment.    Was planning to try use express.    Still wondering why it works on localhost.  I will look into express and see if I can fix it

Comment: Trying this out now